# override HandleUnauthorizedRequest in MVC ,causes Login page doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have 3 areas in my MVC applications `teacher,member,administrator`.each areas have a login page i mean :

```
../aministrator/cms/login
../member/cms/login
../teacher/cms/login
```

My login controller is like this :

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            return View(); // show the login page
        }
        UserRepository ObjUserRepository = new UserRepository();
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(DomainClass.User loginInfo, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ObjUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Email == loginInfo.Email & i.Password == loginInfo.Password).Any())
            {
                DomainClass.User objUser = ObjUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Email == loginInfo.Email & i.Password == loginInfo.Password).FirstOrDefault();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.Name, false);
                if (shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

                if (objUser.Pemission == "professor")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Teacher" });
                }


            }

            return View(loginInfo);
        }
```

I have a `home` controller in each areas .i mean after login the pages should be redirected to `home/index`

My home controller is like this :

```
   [AreaAuthorize("Teacher")]

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Teacher/Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

But the problem is the page can't redirect to `/home/index` and it remains in `cms/login` why ?

Override the authorize :

```
public class AreaAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly string area;

        public AreaAuthorizeAttribute(string area)
        {
            this.area = area;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            string loginUrl = "";

            if (area == "Administrator")
            {
                loginUrl = "~/Administrator/CMS/Login";
            }
            else if (area == "Member")
            {
                loginUrl = "~/User/CMS/Login";
            }
            else if (area == "Teacher")
            {
                loginUrl = "~/Teacher/CMS/Login";
            }

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(loginUrl + "?returnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
        }
    }
```

best regards

Comment: Do you have `<authentication mode="Forms">` defined in web.config?

Comment: @DZL No i don't define any form in webconfig

Comment: You are using forms authentication (FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.Name, false);) so you need to have it defined in web.config. Add it to web.config and it should start working.

Comment: @DZL i want to add this tag :<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authenticatio

Comment: But a problem is left in loginurl which url should i use?Teacher/cms/login or administrator/cms/login

Comment: You can leave it out, loginurl parameter is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the solution as an answer as well:

With MVC 5, the default authentication is based on [OWIN](http://owin.org/) authentication middleware.

If you want to use `FormsAuthentication`, you need to manually add it in the `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="50000000" />
</authentication>
```